# How do I stop Pidgin from running when I log in?

Tags: windows, pidgin

The plugin 'Windows Pidgin Options' is disabled:

[image]

The startup folder `%AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup` contains no reference to Pidgin.

Yet Pidgin still starts up when I log into my account.

Comment: you may change it in preference

Comment: @QuickSilver Can you give me more details, please?

Answer (score -1):

> Open Pidgin. Click "**Tools**," "**Plugins**."
>
> Click on the "**Windows Pidgin Options**" plugin. Click "**Configure Plugin.**"
>
> Uncheck the "**Start Pidgin on Windows startup**" check box. Click "**OK**" to
>   apply the change.

as described [here](http://www.ehow.com/how_8404701_stop-pidgin-autostart.html)

Update:
Type `msconfig` in Run and check startup entries. Disable `pidgin` is checked in startup.

Comment: As explained in the question, the "Windows Pidgin Options" plugin is disabled. I enabled it to follow your instructions, but the option "Start Pidgin on Windows startup" is unchecked by default.

Comment: This might not have worked for you and is not the "right" answer, but it worked for me. Yay.